# Native Terraform AWS Auto-Scaling Group Management with health Checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, autoscaling, healthcheck

I have been using CloudFormation for the past 3 years to manage AWS infrastructure which consists of multiple auto-scaling groups with immutable AMIs (amongst other things). I am trying to rewrite around 5 CloudFormation stacks to Terraform now. Most of if it is not a problem.

The difficult part is the auto-scaling groups, specifically the part where I want to make sure that when a new auto-scaling group replaces the old one, all EC2 and ELB (or target group) health checks must pass before retiring the old auto-scaling group.

With CloudForamtion this was very easy. The stack would create an auto-scaling group with EC2 health check type, ensuring that EC2 checks pass. CloudFormation (with some configuration bits) waits (with a timeout) for a signal from the EC2 instance, indicating that everything is up and running. Sending a signal via EC2s (`cfn`) is possible to send via userdata, where I could continuously ping health status from the target group using AWS CLI.

With Terraform there is no signaling mechanism as the signaling mechanism is exclusive to CloudForamtion. I have seen a solution that uses a mix of both CloudFormation and Terraform, where the auto-scaling group is managed via CloudFormation that is set up via Terraform `aws_cloudformation_stack` resource. I have seen Spinnaker being used in this case as well, which I particularly don't like because it involves creating an auto-scaling group via Terraform and then commenting it out in Terraform. But, I am looking for a pure Terraform native solution.

The closest I have come to a Terraform native solution is to use ELB health check instead of EC2 health check while creating auto-scaling group via Terraform. My questions are:

- Is it recommended to use ELB health checks instead of EC2 health checks? Advantages/disadvantages? If anyone could share their experience in this regard it would be very helpful.
- Is it possible to use both EC2 and ELB or target group health checks in native Terraform?

Comment: I am guessing that your ec2 auto scaling group is the ELB target. In this case, if you choose an ec2 health check, the instances will only be announced to the target group, after they pass the ec2 HC. Then requests will only be passed to healthy targets, i.e. these that pass the additional ELB HC.


If you would like an additional timeout, you can consider an ec2 [ecs cluster service with a grace period](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service#health_check_grace_period_seconds).